# DC motor equation

Tags: motor, dc, brushless-dc-motor

In the references the Brushless DC motor equations are :
(1): L dI/dt+R*I =V - Ke * omega
(2): T=I d(omega)/dt+b * omega +c * sign(omega)
(3): T=Km*I
In this equation by incising the voltage speed is incising linearly but In the practical test the speed is saturated by incising the voltage.
How can I improved these equations? And why this saturation is happened?

Comment: You increased the voltage but the speed didn't increase? That's not expected. What motor and controller did you test, what load did you have on the motor and what was the power supply? Please show us the relevant test data (volts, amps, rpm etc.)

Comment: The equations are good (except you use I for both current and inertia).  Can you specify the controller?

Comment: I had changed the voltage from 0 V to 12 V the speed is incising until 10 V after that the speed  is saturated

Comment: *increasing* I honestly could not understand your question until the comment above that only made sense when *incising* is replaced with *increasing*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the speed even more, you could try to use the principal of flux weakening. You are going to reduce the field flux, which allows you to operate the motor at higher speeds then the rated value, without exceeding the rated value of the terminal voltage.